# Facebook Marketplace Auto Input Text Problem

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to input vehicle information in Facebook marketplace Model input, in the browser console with javascript. I am unable to focus, select, or click I can change the text of the input value but Facebook seems to think nothing is there and doesn't work. Any ideal to make this work with javascript? Thanks

https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/vehicle

I tried the following code.
document.querySelector(`[aria-label="Model"]`).querySelector("input").value="test"

Comment: You'd probably have to find and manipulate the actual React state for that form. Direct DOM manipulation of inputs like this won't do much in modern JavaScript applications.

Comment: I can't even set the cursor in the input field. Any idea why.